# Rails 4 - Get Facebook cookies from Koala gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

I'm making a Rails 4 site for Facebook Canvas using Koala gem. I tried to follow this [Koala on Rails guide](https://github.com/arsduo/koala/wiki/Koala-on-Rails) but always result with `nil` in the `facebook_token`.

Here's my controller (the same as in the guide):

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
def facebook_cookies
    @facebook_cookies ||= Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new.get_user_info_from_cookie(cookies)
end

# app/controllers/photos_controller.rb
def index
  ...
  @access_token = facebook_cookies['access_token']
  @graph = Koala::Facebook::GraphAPI.new(@access_token)
  ...
end
```

I got this error on the line that calls `facebook_cookies`

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

I figure that when I call `.get_user_info_from_cookie(cookies)`, the `cookies` is never declared before.

The doc doesn't mention anything about how to obtain that variable. Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. It turned out, that the cookies have never been set.

For setting the cookies, you need the [Facebook Javascript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.1)

afterwards you need something like this in your JS:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  return FB.init({
    appId: YOUR_FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    cookie: true
  });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I also found out few days ago that the cookie must be set from Javascript. I don't think there's straight forward way to do it on server-side.